# QWidget, созданный в отдельном QThread и добавленный в основной QWidget, отображается в отдельном окне

Tags: qt, qt5, 3d

Когда я создаю Qt3DWindow в отделом потоке, конвертирую его в QWidget и добавляю к основному, то отображается два окна. Если все это проделываю в одном потоке, то отображается одно(QWidget встроен как надо)

```
auto view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
QWidget* container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
```

Comment: работать с гуйнёй можно только из основного потока.

Answer (score 1):

Как написано в [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html), всё что связано с графическим интерфейсом должно работать только в главном потоке. Все виджеты, а также некоторые другие связанные классы (вроде `QPixmap`) не будут работать в других потоках.